# Survey score difference between the first call of a certain call category and subsequent calls of the same call category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with call center data. The dataframe looks like the following:

```
    member_id  survey_score  call_reason  call_direction      time_stamp
0     bob13         0          returns       inbound      2019-03-18 10:12:00
1     ub40          5         complaint      inbound      2019-03-19 11:12:00
2     bob13         7          returns       outbound     2019-03-19 09:15:00
3     todd100       3         order_error    inbound      2019-03-20 10:15:00
4     ub40          2         complaint      inbound      2019-03-21 12:11:00
5     todd100       7         order_error    outbound     2019-03-22 08:10:00
6     ub40          1         complaint      outbound     2019-03-22 11:09:00
7     ron34         6         exchange       inbound      2019-03-22 13:09:00
8     ron34         7         returns         inbound      2019-03-24 15:03:00
```

The output that I am looking for is as follows:

```
    member_id    call_reason     score_differential          
0     bob13       returns               7
1     ub40       complaint             -1
2     todd100    order_error            4
```

So basically, I am looking to get the difference between the first inbound call survey score of a member, and the very next outbound call survey score from the same member, and only if the call reason is the same as well.

As a small business owner, I'm trying to do the data science stuff for my company myself to save some dough. Unfortunately, I am a complete rookie in this regards and am having great difficulty with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I am using jupyter notebooks and pandas on my local machine through anaconda.

Please help me do this in an quicker, easier, and more logical way.

I've tried a ridiculous amount of ways to get the output correct but I am still having great difficulty. It also feels as I'm overcomplicating things.
First I get the call order. I then create some columns for the first score inbound call score and score differential. Then I get a list of all of the unique member Id's to iterate over, and finally I made a giant loop with a bunch of logic in which I just get lost.

Also, in the first iteration of this code I did not take into regard the call direction. Furthermore, I got the average of all subsequent calls of a member with the same call reason, then got the difference between that and the first call. I no longer want to do that.

```
df['call_order'] = df_repeat.groupby('member_id')['timestamp'].rank(ascending=True, method = 'dense')

df["first_call_survey_score"] = ""
df["first_call_survey_score"] = np.nan
df["score_differential"] = ""
df["score_differential"] = np.nan

member_list = df['member_id'].unique()

unscorable = 0
for member in member_list:
    try:
        count = 2
        temp = df.loc[df['member_id'] == member]
        temp = temp.drop_duplicates(subset='call_order', keep="first")
        num_calls = temp['member_id'].count()
        first_call = temp.query("call_order == 1")
        first_survey_score = first_call['survey_score'].values[0]
        reason = first_call['call_reason'].values[0]
        sumscore = 0
        legit_call_count = 0
        while count <= num_calls:
                next_call = temp.query("call_order == @count")
                if reason == next_call['call_reason'].values[0]:
                    sumscore = sumscore + next_call['survey_score'].values[0]
                    count = count + 1
                    legit_call_count = legit_call_count + 1 
                elif reason != next_call['call_reason'].values[0] and count == num_calls:
                    count = 20
                elif reason != next_call['call_reason'].values[0]:
                    count = count + 1
                    next_call = temp.query("call_order == @count")
                    reason = next_call['call_reason'].values[0]
                    first_survey_score = next_call['survey_score'].values[0]
                else: count = count + 1

        if legit_call_count == 1:
            df.loc[((df_repeat['member_id'] == member)),['score_differential']] = sumscore / legit_call_count - first_survey_score
        elif count == 20:unscorable = unscorable + 1
        else: 
            df.loc[((df['member_id'] == member)),['score_differential']] = sumscore / legit_call_count - first_survey_score
    except Exception as exception:
            unscorable = unscorable + 1

print(unscorable, "Callers could not be scored")
```

Comment: If you have another question you should ask a new question, not change an existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach, where outgoing calls are given a unique id by member/reason, and that id is back filled to incoming calls. Then the last incoming call for a given (member, reason, Id) is paired up the outgoing call for the same (member, reason, Id), and the differential is computed. Note: I added a second call sequence for user bob13, to show that this handles multiple calls for same user.

```py
txt = """\
   member_id  survey_score  call_reason  call_direction      time_stamp
     bob13         0          returns       inbound      2019-03-18T10:12:00
     ub40          5         complaint      inbound      2019-03-19T11:12:00
     bob13         7          returns       outbound     2019-03-19T09:15:00
     todd100       3         order_error    inbound      2019-03-20T10:15:00
     ub40          2         complaint      inbound      2019-03-21T12:11:00
     todd100       7         order_error    outbound     2019-03-22T08:10:00
     ub40          1         complaint      outbound     2019-03-22T11:09:00
     ron34         6         exchange       inbound      2019-03-22T13:09:00
     ron34         7         returns         inbound      2019-03-24T15:03:00
     bob13         2          returns       inbound      2019-03-25T10:12:00
     bob13         3          returns       outbound     2019-03-27T09:15:00
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=1, index_col=False)

grp = df.query('call_direction=="outbound"').\
    groupby(['member_id', 'call_reason'])
df['OutId'] = grp.time_stamp.transform(lambda x: x.rank())
print()
print(df)

grp = df.groupby(['member_id', 'call_reason'])
df['Id'] = grp.OutId.transform(lambda x: x.bfill())
print()
print(df)

inbnd_score = df.query('call_direction=="inbound"').\
    groupby(['member_id', 'call_reason', 'Id']).survey_score.last()
outbnd_score = df.query('call_direction=="outbound"').\
    groupby(['member_id', 'call_reason', 'Id']).survey_score.last()

ddf = pd.concat([inbnd_score, outbnd_score], axis=1,
                keys=['inbnd', 'outbnd'])
ddf['score_differential'] = ddf.outbnd - ddf.inbnd
print()
print(ddf)
```

Output:

```
   member_id  survey_score  call_reason call_direction           time_stamp  OutId
0      bob13             0      returns        inbound  2019-03-18T10:12:00    NaN
1       ub40             5    complaint        inbound  2019-03-19T11:12:00    NaN
2      bob13             7      returns       outbound  2019-03-19T09:15:00    1.0
3    todd100             3  order_error        inbound  2019-03-20T10:15:00    NaN
4       ub40             2    complaint        inbound  2019-03-21T12:11:00    NaN
5    todd100             7  order_error       outbound  2019-03-22T08:10:00    1.0
6       ub40             1    complaint       outbound  2019-03-22T11:09:00    1.0
7      ron34             6     exchange        inbound  2019-03-22T13:09:00    NaN
8      ron34             7      returns        inbound  2019-03-24T15:03:00    NaN
9      bob13             2      returns        inbound  2019-03-25T10:12:00    NaN
10     bob13             3      returns       outbound  2019-03-27T09:15:00    2.0

   member_id  survey_score  call_reason call_direction           time_stamp  OutId   Id
0      bob13             0      returns        inbound  2019-03-18T10:12:00    NaN  1.0
1       ub40             5    complaint        inbound  2019-03-19T11:12:00    NaN  1.0
2      bob13             7      returns       outbound  2019-03-19T09:15:00    1.0  1.0
3    todd100             3  order_error        inbound  2019-03-20T10:15:00    NaN  1.0
4       ub40             2    complaint        inbound  2019-03-21T12:11:00    NaN  1.0
5    todd100             7  order_error       outbound  2019-03-22T08:10:00    1.0  1.0
6       ub40             1    complaint       outbound  2019-03-22T11:09:00    1.0  1.0
7      ron34             6     exchange        inbound  2019-03-22T13:09:00    NaN  NaN
8      ron34             7      returns        inbound  2019-03-24T15:03:00    NaN  NaN
9      bob13             2      returns        inbound  2019-03-25T10:12:00    NaN  2.0
10     bob13             3      returns       outbound  2019-03-27T09:15:00    2.0  2.0

                           inbnd  outbnd  score_differential
member_id call_reason Id
bob13     returns     1.0      0       7                   7
                      2.0      2       3                   1
todd100   order_error 1.0      3       7                   4
ub40      complaint   1.0      2       1                  -1
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great with the data I'm working with. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying to do another analysis and was running into a few errors. I am looking to get the difference between the first inbound call survey score of a member, and the very next call survey score with the concurrent call being either inbound or outbound. Again, this is only if the call reason is the same as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps use `second_score = df.groupby(['member_id', 'call_reason', 'Id']).survey_score.nth(1)` instead of `outbnd_score`? And if you don't care about multiple calls per user, you can drop the "Id" column from the groups.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I have been trying some additional analysis and have been running into issues, you can find it in the edit above. Again, I would really appreciate further help!

Comment: Hi @GlupiDebil, since question revisions should be made to the question, not an answer, feel free to update the question, but also note that: if you can generalize the central question(s) and create a new question, it would attract more attention than editing an existing question. And, since you ask well-defined questions -- I just don't have time to answer them at this time -- if you don't a response, you could try earning SO rep to create a bounty, or putting the question on a site like Upwork. Best of luck!